# How to get the count of a query efficiently

Tags: support, dev-tip

To get the count of a query without returning results, simply specify `pagesize=0`.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?filter=mike&sort=name&pagesize=0

```
{
  "total": 1161,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 0,
  "users": []
}
```

Comment: Should be just `pagesize=0`.  Deviations from this are bugs.

Comment: I thing dev-tips like these should be tagged support, not discussion.  (Maybe both?)

Comment: @jjn - i think you are going to get pushback on tagging support. Typically support tag means, 'Hey, I need support', where as a devtip says 'Hey, here is some technical implementation information' . they are informational. perhaps the way to go is to add dev-tip to required tags so that it can stand alone

Comment: @code, well if you take the support tag at face-value, the word "support" means helping people use the API.  That is exactly what dev-tip is doing.  Just because a majority of support questions are "help my mouse is broken" doesn't mean it can't also be pre-emptive tips on how to better use the API.

Comment: @code, also, 'discussion' really fits horribly.  There is really nothing to discuss about here.  That is clearly the best way to get a result set size without pulling any data.

Comment: @jjn - ok, I can see that. I didn't see a clear choice when i tagged it as I did not want kevin to be deluged with 'help, my api is broken' false alarms. But a convention can be argued for support+devtip. I agree. now.